# iOS Uploading to AppStore - Unable to create configuration directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, itunes

iOS App Upload to app store (**XCODE**) fails saying:

***"Unable to create configuration directory. Cannot save local copy of remote diagonistic configuration; local path is not writable."***

Any ideas/thoughts?

[image]

---

- ANSWER
  Simple thing that solved it:

  1. Right Click on your Home folder & Click Get Info.
  2. Uncheck the Locked Checkbox.

Comment: if you found an answer, post it as answer please. Don't edit the question

Comment: @Krishnabhadra : Stack is not allowing me for the same due to not enough points.

Comment: answering questions doesn't need points(reputation). Can't you see a **Answer your question** button at the bottom?